# Navigating Excel via Row for value change respectively as per category

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I have data in sheet `'DATA'` with this values :
[image: sourcedata]

Then I have the 'navigator' sheet called '`NAV'` with this structure :
[image]

In `'NAV' G9` cell, I have this formula :

> 

```
     =INDEX(COLUMN(DATA!$H$4:$N$566)-7,
AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(DATA!$H$4:$N$4)-COLUMN(DATA!$H$4)+1/
(DATA!$H$3:$N$3=G$7),ROWS(G$9:G9)))
```

The issue is, I try to drag down from `G9:G17` (remarks : it will be more than that), but the value didnt change accordingly as per `'DATA'` sheet. The value taken also wrong. If I put value 'PER' in '`NAV' G7`, cell `G9:G7` will change to ''AAA', 'BBB, 'CCC' and so on respectively. Those values will change when I put 'T1', 'T2', and so on based on `'DATA'` legend.

Can you guys please help? Already change here and there and it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines, you need the `COUNTIF()` function for the headers i.e. `PER`, `T1`, `T2` etc :

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$H$4:$N$13,
 AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(DATA!$G$4:$G$13)-ROW(DATA!$G$4)+1)/
 ($F9=DATA!$G$4:$G$13),COUNTIF(G$7:G7,G7)),
 MATCH(G$7,DATA!$H$3:$N$3,0)),"")
```

---

Or, simply can use `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`+`MATCH()`

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!$H$4:$N$13,
 MATCH(DATA!$G4,NAV!$F$9:$F$16,0),
 MATCH(G$7,DATA!$H$3:$N$3,0)),"")
```

---

In `MS365` it would be using `FILTER()` & `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(F9:F16,DATA!G4:G13,FILTER(DATA!H4:N13,(G7=DATA!H3:N3)),"")
```

---